# Resizing partition

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, hard-disk

I've got a server (Ubuntu 16.04) which has 6TB of total HDD. When I checked up on the disk usage just a minute ago, I only saw 1TB being 'recognised':
https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/Hi5ap4q.png

How do I expand this /home partition, without losing the data on it?
I'm a bit confused due to this:
https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/Hi5aQLl.png

Comment: I might have a solution, but could you please [edit] your question first and get rid of the images and replace them by text so I can copy-paste the text into my answer?  After you've done this, leave a comment @Fabby

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 2x 3TB drives in a RAID1 configuration (mirrored). So you can only use 1x 3TB worth of space, but if one drive dies, the data is still available on the other one.

You can't expand the /home partition because there is no unused space to expand to. The drive is fully in use, about 1TB for / root partition and 2TB for /home partition (plus a small /boot partition).

So there is nothing wrong with the install per se, it's fully utilizing the available hard drive space.

To make the /home partition larger, you'd have to shrink the / root partition accordingly. However, that is not easily done in a RAID setup without LVM.

Unless you wish to reinstall, break redundancy or do in-place conversions, the easiest solution here would be to just make use of the space by putting some of your files on the / root filesystem, too.

Comment: There's no need for a RAID1 config --> it's just a plex server. However, how can I undo this, without losing data from either one of the drives? I want both drives to be a total sum of storage, instead of raid1.

Comment: @Sam you could `mdadm --grow` the /home RAID1 to RAID0, that would give you roughly 4TB instead of current 2TB. A dead drive will lose you that data completely.

Comment: how about shrinking the 1TB / (root) partition to 200GB, and add 800GB to the /home partition? How can I accomplish that? I've just been fiddling around and I can't get it to work.